# How to capture onclick event in disabled EditText in Android App

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext

I have a EditText which I am presenting as disabled so that user cannot edit the contents and also to avoid popping-up keyboard. But now I want to capture onclick event in the EditText and  identify the individual words that are being clicked.
Any help is most welcome.

Thanks,
Balkrishna.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

On your `EditText` set attributes `android:focusable="false"` and `android:enabled="true"`.
And set `OnClickListener` to that `EditText`. The click on that Edittext triggers the `onClick()` method but it can't be edited. I just tried it.

Comment: thanks Rajkiran.. now I can get the onclick event.. but the next problem is to get hold on to the word being clicked..

Comment: Well, I don't see any way to achieve that. You will have to play around with it. And don't forget to post the answer if you get the solution for the same. Best luck!

Comment: Also set  android:longClickable="false", without on long click it would go into select/paste mode

Comment: You'll also want to consider `android:cursorVisible="false"` to avoid the user from seeing a real cursor for a quick second when clicking the EditText.

Answer (score 6):

You can make the component unclickable by using.

```
editText.setClickable(false);
```

To make the component look visually disabled by decreasing the **Alpha** value.

```
editText.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

It will allow you to set an **OnTouchListener** on your component by which you can perform your desired operations.

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Component is disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: multiple times calling on single touch

Comment: @ChandraKiran try returning true

Comment: Or try doing this inside the listener:

if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    // your code
}